# Overflow to next Page not align to top

Tags: jasper-reports

When the value inside long text is too long so that it overflow to the next page, the content in the next page is not starting from the very beginning of the page instead, according to my observation, the text in the next page is starting from the same height as it  is.

[image]

How can I fix it? Any setting is required? Since this looks really awkward.

Comment: This is interesting, however there is no setting that you can use, can you show some jrxml you tried?. I'm not really convinced you can do it, maybe creating a special report design, it will not be easy